# AttributeError: 'MyStreamer' object has no attribute 'statuses' where MyStreamer class extends TwythonStreamer class

Tags: python, python-2.7, twitter

I am using Twython to collect data from Twitter's Streaming api but am getting the error AttributeError: 'MyStreamer' object has no attribute 'statuses'

```
app_key = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
app_secret = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
oauth_token = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
oauth_token_secret = 'XXXXXXX'

client_args = {
            'proxies':{
                        'http': 'http://x.x.x.x:xxxx',
                        'https': 'https://x.x.x.x:xxxx',
                        }
        }


class MyStreamer(TwythonStreamer):

def __init__(self):
    self.app_key = app_key
    self.app_secret = app_secret
    self.oauth_token = oauth_token
    self.oauth_token_secret = oauth_token_secret
    self.client_args = client_args

def on_success(self, data):
    if 'text' in data:
        print data['text'].encode('utf-8')

def on_error(self, status_code, data):
    print status_code

if __name__ == '__main__':
    stream = MyStreamer()
    stream.statuses.filter(track = 'twitter')
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove '**init**(self)' function and its contents and then try.